# ajax call working normally for small amt of data but not working for large data

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                url: "xxxx.aspx/Name",
                data: JSON.stringify("{'ID':'" + ID + "','Date':'" + Date + "'}"),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",          
                success: function (datab) {
                    debugger;
                    var data2 = $.parseJSON(datab.d).Table;
                    //  var data2 = $.xml2json(datab.d).Table;
                    binddata(data2);
                }
            });
```

---

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static object xxxxx(int? ID, DateTime? Date)
    {

        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer JSSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
         object json = "";

       // StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = client.xxxxx(ID, Date);
            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {

              //  System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb);
               // ds.WriteXml(writer, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
               // Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer json = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();
                json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Formatting.Indented);

             //  return json;
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Empty);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Empty);
        }

      //  return json.Tostring();
        return json;
    }
```

now this working superbly for some small amount of json data but at the  time when large amount of came it's not working. the control not entering into ajax call at this time.

And when i debugged in the chrome it returns

POST http://localhost:51048/xxxx.aspx/name 500 (Internal Server Error)
send 
jQuery.extend.ajax 
(anonymous function) 
jQuery.event.dispatch 
elemData.handle

Your help will be appreciated greatly...:)

Comment: what is large amount? Usually a web-server will have a maximum limit of data that it will accept in any one request. It could be that your server settings are causing the request to be rejected

Comment: It will be your server config. To avoid posting denial-of-service attacks your server will, by default, only accept data up to a fixed limit. You need to change your web.config (or equivalent) settings to allow larger data transfers.

Comment: its json data in large amount@loopo

Comment: The default limit in ASP.NET for a request is 4 MB, is "large amount" that much? (Note that the question doesn't really have anything to do with either jQuery or AJAX as it was tagged.)

Comment: its a json data nearly upto 700 records @Guffa

Comment: i'm getting entire large json data from wcfservice to dataset in code behind file . there i'm converting it into json and returning it.  it works upto 250 records fine when it exceeds it's the problem internal service error

Comment: @mukesh: You need to debug the server code or examine the response returned to find out what the exact exception is. There might be a limitation in the JSON serializer. The data returned from a request is virtually unlimited so generally the only limit would be available memory. There has to be something wrong in the code itself.